# Is it possible to resume Java execution after exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have a ParentClass in a JAR, but not source code. I am implementing a SubClass, but i need to handle some corner cases.

```
class ParentClass {
    void foo() {
       … // lots of code 1
       ; // can possibly throw NullPointerException 
       … // lots of code 2
    }
}
class SubClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    void foo() {
       try {super.foo();}
       catch(NullPointerException npe) {… /*handle exception*/}
       finally {… /* resume lots of code 2 ? */}
    }
}
```

Is there a way to run the `//lots of code 2` part after handling the exception in the overriding method? I don't want to duplicate code, and cannot modify the ParentClass.

P.S: The NullPointerException problem wasn't there in the ParentClass. But due to a different instantiation in SubClass, this problem may arise.

Comment: You cannot. Try solving the NPE,instead...

Comment: You should generally fix NPEs rather than catching them.

Comment: "But due to a different instantiation in SubClass, this problem may arise." Fix the different instantiation in `SubClass`.

Comment: You are including the statement, which can throw an error, inside a try-catch block, right?

Comment: @progyammer Not the statement. The ParentClass method will throw the exception in runtime. Actually, i don't need use that variable anymore in my subclass, but it's used in other subclasses of ParentClass.

Comment: Others tell you to fix your NPE. I'll tell you why: an NPE is a programmer's logic error, meaning that *you* made an error in what you think is correct. So, no, it's never okay to leave it as is. Hence people telling you to fix your NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You cannot just jump back into the middle of a method.

If you don't want to copy-paste the code in there (good call!) you have to put the shared code into a separate method that your subclass can call.

Or you could put the part that might throw the NullPointerException into a separate method and override it in the subclass (so that it no longer throws).

> But due to a different instantiation in SubClass, this problem may arise.

Maybe you can sidestep the exception altogether by changing the way you do this instantiation? Maybe provide a "dummy object" for the thing that is currently `null`? Something that doesn't do anything harmful, but prevents the exception?

Comment: Thanks! Looks like i need to "hack" my way around this limitation by creating dummy stuff and then overriding with actual stuff.
`@Override void foo() { super.ref = new Object(); super.foo(); super.ref = null; this.ref.doSomething();}` I want it null because i want to be semantic in my code.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, you cannot move back there. However, you might be able to [refactor](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) `Parent.foo()` to something like this:

```
class ParentClass {
    protected void foo() { //  made it protected so it's overridable
       stuffBeforeNPE(); // Extract Method Refactoring
       codeWithPossiblyNPE(); // Extract Method Refactoring
       stuffAfterNPE(); // Extract Method Refactoring
    }

    protected void stuffBeforeNPE() { ... } // you might want to add params and return values
    protected void codeWithPossiblyNPE() { ... }
    stuffAfterNPE() { ... }
}
```

Now, your child class might look like this:

```
class SubClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
      stuffBeforeNPE();
       try {
          codeWithPossiblyNPE();
       } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
          … /*handle exception*/
       }
       stuffAfterNPE();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I think we can try adding a local try-catch block:**
Example Scenario:
Lets say we have program in which a code block that could do some math operation; and based on our logic we expect a exception, which may be considered non-fatal.

so we may just want to ignore this exception and go to other functionality of the main program - exactly to the question:

**I thought to do this:**

- put that block of code in a function and declare the function to throw an exception
- in the main program, where we call the function , we can do so by using a local try-catch block
- so incase we have an exception this try-catch solves it and then continues with the remaining code**

may be an example would do good:

```
public class Main
{
    public static double divideByInputs(int a, int b) throws ArithmeticException{
        return (a/b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        //local try-catch block
            try {
                divideByInputs(3,0); // throws Exception
            }
            catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                // Exception handler
                System.out.println("Divided by zero operation cannot possible");
            }
        //remaining part of code
        System.out.println("Though there was an expetion we conintue to print chocolates");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** I read many other answers on similar questions, where I understood that having a exception in program is kinda 'bad' - 'cause why have, even, predictable errors!
I wrote this answer as a suggestion...
I am still a newbie to the world of programming, Thanks for reading!